# How can I find images in a directory?

Tags: ssh

How can I find 5 JPEG files whose names contain the "intro" word in some form, in a directory? Also there is a hidden one file among these 5.

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://www.maketecheasier.com/find-a-file-in-linux/

Comment: The [manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/find.1.html) for find, if you are interested in that.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment - what have you tried? what part of it exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @steeldriver yes, I tried ( sudo find / -name *.jpeg -print) and I think it's work in the right way, but I still have a problem with the hidden image and I can not find it

Comment: @ IT Gremlin thank you.

Comment: @Graham yes it helped me a lot, thank you, but I still have a problem with the hidden image and I can not find it

Answer (score 0):

according to your description I would try:

```
find . -type f -iname "*intro*"
```

This will also spit out hidden files in the current directory.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: thank you for help, but I still have a problem with the hidden image and I can not find it